# Why does an IllegalThreadStateException occur when Thread.start is called again

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class SieveGenerator{

static int N = 50;
public static void main(String args[]){

    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    int f[] = new int[N];

    //fill array with 0,1,2...f.length
    for(int j=0;j<f.length;j++){
        f[j]=j;
    }

    f[0]=0;f[1]=0;//eliminate these cases

    int p=2;

    removeNonPrime []t = new removeNonPrime[cores];

    for(int i = 0; i < cores; i++){
        t[i] = new removeNonPrime(f,p);
    }

    while(p <= (int)(Math.sqrt(N))){
        t[p%cores].start();//problem here because you cannot start a thread which has already started(IllegalThreadStateException)
        try{
            t[p%cores].join();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        //get the next prime
        p++;
        while(p<=(int)(Math.sqrt(N))&&f[p]==0)p++;
    }


    //count primes
    int total = 0;
    System.out.println();

    for(int j=0; j<f.length;j++){
        if(f[j]!=0){
            total++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Number of primes up to %d = %d",f.length,total);
}
}


class removeNonPrime extends Thread{
int k;
int arr[];

public removeNonPrime(int arr[], int k){
    this.arr = arr;
    this.k = k;
}

public void run(){
    int j = k*k;
    while(j<arr.length){
        if(arr[j]%k == 0)arr[j]=0;
        j=j+arr[k];

    }
}
}
```

Hi I'm getting an `IllegalThreadStateException` when I run my code and I've figured it's because I am trying to start a thread that has already been started. So how could I kill 
or stop the thread each time, to get around this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> how could I kill or stop the thread each time, to get around this problem?

The answer is, you can't. Once started, a `Thread` may not be restarted. This is clearly documented in the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for `Thread`. Instead, what you really want to do is `new` an instance of `RemoveNonPrime` each time you come around in your loop.

You have a few other problems in your code.
First, you need to increment `p` before using it again:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cores; i++){
    t[i] = new removeNonPrime(f,p); //<--- BUG, always using p=2 means only multiples of 2 are cleared
}
```

Second, you might be multithreaded, but you aren't concurrent. The code you have basically only allows one thread to run at a time:

```
while(p <= (int)(Math.sqrt(N))){
    t[p%cores].start();//
    try{
        t[p%cores].join(); //<--- BUG, only the thread which was just started can be running now
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //get the next prime
    p++;
    while(p<=(int)(Math.sqrt(N))&&f[p]==0)p++;
}
```

Just my $0.02, but what you are trying to do might work, but the logic for selecting the next smallest prime will not always pick a prime, for example if one of the other threads hasn't processed that part of the array yet.

Here is an approach using an ExecutorService, there are some blanks (...) that you will have to fill in:

```
/* A queue to trick the executor into blocking until a Thread is available when offer is called */
public class SpecialSyncQueue<E> extends SynchronousQueue<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        try {
            put(e);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(cores, cores, new SpecialSyncQueue(), ...);
void pruneNonPrimes() {
    //...
    while(p <= (int)(Math.sqrt(N))) {
        executor.execute(new RemoveNonPrime(f, p));
        //get the next prime
        p++;
        while(p<=(int)(Math.sqrt(N))&&f[p]==0)p++;
    }


    //count primes
    int total = 0;
    System.out.println();

    for(int j=0; j<f.length;j++){
        if(f[j]!=0){
            total++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Number of primes up to %d = %d",f.length,total);
}



class RemoveNonPrime extends Runnable {
    int k;
    int arr[];

    public RemoveNonPrime(int arr[], int k){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public void run(){
        int j = k*k;
        while(j<arr.length){
            if(arr[j]%k == 0)arr[j]=0;
            j+=k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hoper every instance of the thread is taken care of by garbage collection or whatever it is that cleans up temporary created objects. Or, does the thread and its created objects "die" by themselves... Cats have 9 lives, and threads only 1?

Comment: Once started, a `Thread` executes its `run` method. When `run` return, execution of the thread terminates and resources are freed. Any object which was only reachable via that thread will eventually be marked for garbage collection. But yes, a `Thread` only has one life. `ExecutorService` works around this by giving the `Thread` more tasks as `Runnable` via a `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement Runnable instead and use new Thread( $Runnable here ).start() or use a ExecutorService to reuse threads.

Comment: Would using Runnable not just give me the same problem or when I start the thread, would it stop automatically when finished?

Comment: No; with new Thread( Runnable ).start() a new thread is created and started. The runnable object can be used more than once. Yes it would stop if finished. Using an executor service would be probably better if you create really many threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
* It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
* In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
* execution.
*
* @exception IllegalThreadStateException  if the thread was already started
*/
public synchronized void start() {
```

In Android, document still mention that we will get  `IllegalThreadStateException if the thread was already started`.
However for some device it will not throw this exception (tested on Kyocera 7.0). In some popular device like Samsung, HTC, it throw throw the exception normally

I answer here because the Android question is mark as duplicated to this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does an IllegalThreadStateException occur when Thread.start is
>   called again

Because JDK/JVM implementers coded `Thread.start()` method that way. Its a reasonable functional expectation to be able to restart a thread after a thread has completed its execution and that is what being suggested in chrisbunney's answer ( and I have put in a comment in that answer ) but if you look at `Thread.start()` implementation , the very first line is ,

```
if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

where `threadStatus  == 0` means `NEW` state so my guess is that implementation doesn't resets this state to zero after execution has completed & thread is left in `TERMINATED` state ( non - zero state ). So when you create a new `Thread` instance on same `Runnable` , you basically reset this state to zero.

Also, I noticed the usage of word - **may** & **never** in same paragraph as different behavior is being pointed out by Phan Van Linh on some OSes,

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

I guess what they are trying to say in above Javadoc that even if you don't get `IllegalThreadStateException` on certain OS, its not legal in Java/Thread class way & you might get unexpected behavior.

The famous thread state diagrams depict the same scenario - no going back from dead state to new.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPools can be used for delivering tasks to set number of threads. When initiating you set the number of threads. Then you add tasks for the pool. And after you can block until all tasks have finished processing. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Threadpooldemo.htm) is some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure I understand the question.  All the methods for stopping threads that are executed from other threads are deprecated; the way to stop a thread is to have it check a variable that it and another thread can access (perhaps a *volatile* variable), and have the running thread check it occasionally to see if it should exit on its own.

I cannot tell why/whether you want to eliminate the running thread and use another one, and I cannot see how the different threads are going to help execute your overall goal any faster.  But it's possible I'm just not understanding the math.

Answer (score 0):

The [Thread.isAlive()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) method can tell you if the Thread has already been started. Simply do this where you want to start your thread:

```
   if(!t[p%cores].isAlive()){
       t[p%cores].start();
   }
```

Comment: Javadoc from Phan Van Linh's answer is clearly saying - **a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution** . I am only confused by the usage of word **may**. Not sure if its allowed in certain situations & not allowed in certain situation. If you try to start a thread after `if(!thread.isAlive())` ..it will result in `IllegalThreadStateException` if it was started before.

Comment: Indeed his answer does say that. Please do note that my answer is roughly 6.5 years older than his, and roughly 8.5 years old at the time of this comment, so I don't know whether my answer is referring to the same version of java that his is or whether my answer is still relevant (I've not written Java for a while). I also don't know what's supposed to happen to historic answers like this when the world moves on around them

Comment: As to your question about "may not", I read that as "not allowed to". For example, Question: "may I restart a thread once it is started?", Answer: "No, you may not"

Comment: Thanks for your input & I understand the version & historical dilemma. I checked Java **1.1.8 documentation** & its mentioned there for `start` method - **Throws: IllegalThreadStateException if the thread was already started.** Method signature and Javadoc are a little different than today but functionality around thread restart seems to be constant.I guess, they simply added this line in doc for better clarity- **It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.**.